# Convergents of a continued fraction inequality

Tags: induction, continued-fractions

If $\alpha$ is an irrational number and $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ for $n\geqslant 0$ are the convergents to $\alpha$.

How can one show that $p_{n+1}q_n - p_nq_{n+1} = \pm 1$ for all $n \geqslant 0$, where:

[image]

I have attempted to show this by induction assuming it holds for every pair  up to some pair $n=k$ but there doesn’t appear to be a clear way to   simplify the blue terms at the end of the inductive step.

[image]

Comment: It's not true in general. It holds for $m = n \pm 1$, but we have e.g. $p_nq_{n-2} - p_{n-2}q_n = (-1)^n a_n$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please look at my half-answer above as the terms in blue at the bottom are the terms I can’t get rid of.

Comment: Use the recurrence only for the terms with index $k+1$, $$p_{k+1}q_k - p_kq_{k+1} = (a_{k+1} p_k + p_{k-1})q_k - p_k(a_{k+1} q_k - q_{k-1})\,.$$ That gives you nice cancellation.

Comment: Actually I think that result you wrote in your 1st comment helps but I’m not sure where you got it from

Comment: Your second comment helps a lot thanks.

Comment: I learned the hard way that it's best not to try to re-invent the wheel.  See chapter 1 of [khinchin - continued fractions](http://bit.ly/pdf-khinchin).